# Location of a double cap symbol

Tags: symbols

I've been searching for this symbol

[image]

in a variety of palettes, but have been unable to find it. Anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: This is one uncommon symbol. Couldn't find it in any set of LaTeX symbols and it is unknown to Detexify. Perhaps you could rotate << or stack BigVee?

Comment: Do you mean the "slower" button on an animator or a character?  The button is an image, I believe.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes I do mean the slower button on the animator. I'm trying to write an introduction to Manipulate for my next Introduction to Mathematica lecture at our college. How would I rotate the << symbol?

Comment: ︾ -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125263/

Comment: @MichaelE2 I was able to copy and paste an image and when I clicked on it, this suggestions type bar popped up and I selected transform tools and changed its size.

Comment: Judging from its behavior under magnification and from monitoring LinkSnooper, my guess is that it's simple vector graphics created internally by the Front End.